# Animation in unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to animate my main character's attack , but when I add all the frames together the character shifts a little bit back and forth to compensate for the change in width. Only the characters arm is drawn differently but since it changes the width of the entire picture ,unity changes the position of the character to compensate for the change in width.

I know it's hard to ask for help on animation since I cannot provide a video of my problem , but if anyone has an idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In the sprite editor, make sure the character sprite's pivot is always in the same spot.

[image: How to edit a sprite's pivot]